# What is happening different to my TIFF between export data and arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, georeferencing, fme-form, sentinel-1

I am working in FME with TIFFs downloaded from sentinel-1 (SAR). These TIFFs display correctly in ArcMap but in FME is loses its spatial reference and a bound box calculation gives the number of pixels in the tiff from the upper left corner at 0,0.

I concluded that this is an issue with the flavour of TIFF, so I exported the tiff in ArcGIS to a new file. FME could read this fine. A bounding box output would appear in the right place.

As I'm trying to automate a workflow, a manual export in arcmap won't be good enough. I've tried using the Python Caller in FME with

```
def processFeature(feature):
    origraster = feature.getAttribute('path_windows')
    print "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! RECREATING RASTER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    print origraster
    newraster = origraster.replace(".tiff", "_arcgis.img")
    print newraster
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(arcpy.sa.Raster(origraster),newraster)
    feature.setAttribute("newraster", newraster)

    pass
```

This creates a new raster (I've tried .tif, this is another test of using ERDAS Imagine .img) but one with has the same problems as the original.

I've tried RasterToOtherFormat_conversion but have the same problem.

Is there a difference between the process in exporting from ArcMap and copying in arcpy? And if so how can I remove this?

This is the info given in FME data inspector of the Python produced .img
[image]

And this is what it sees if the .img is produced by manually exporting in ArcMap
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded a file and gave it a try (finding the same results as you by default). However... if you set the Apply GCPs parameter:

[image]

...choosing an appropriate interpolation method, then the data appears in the correct spot and is tagged with the coordinate system:

[image]

My guess is that ArcGIS applies those values automatically, whereas FME doesn't do that by default. I don't know what interpolation method ArcGIS uses though.